# Load a low-res background image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am working on a project where images should load at low quality initially and later it would load at higher resolution.

Comment: Maybe you can look up to filterQuality property of Image widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/filterQuality.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using  [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) :

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: 'YOUR_URL_HIGH_RES',
            placeholder:(context, _) => Image.network('YOUR_URL_LOW_RES')
          ),
```

As documentation claims - placeholder will be shown until your image at `imageUrl` is loaded and cached. I think it fits your use-case.